# Simplifying factorial expressions to show properties of Pascal's triangle

Tags: factorial, binomial-theorem

I'm trying to show that in Pascal's triangle, a number is the the sum of the two terms in the row above it.  My working is as follows:

$\frac{n!}{(r-1)!(n-(r-1))!}$+$\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$

= $\frac{n!}{(r-1)!(n-r+1) \times (n-r)!}$+$\frac{n!}{r \times (r-1)!(n-r)!}$

= $\frac{r\times(r-1)!(n-r)!n!+(r-1)!(n-r+1)\times(n-r)!n!}{(r-1)!(n-r+1)\times(n-r)!r\times(r-1)!(n-r)!}$

= $\frac{r\times(n-r)!n!+(n-r+1)\times(n-r)!}{(n-r+1\times(n-r)!r(n-r)!n!}$

= $\frac{n!\times r + n! \times (n-r+1)}{r(n-r+1)!}$,

which seems to be missing an ${r!}$ as per the fourth line of the given solution.

The textbook solution is given as follows:

${n\choose r-1}$$x^{r-1}$ + ${n\choose r}$$x^{r}$

= $\frac{n!}{(r-1)!(n-(r-1))!}$+$\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$

= $\frac{n!}{(r-1)!(n-r+1) \times (n-r)!}$+$\frac{n!}{r \times (r-1)!(n-r)!}$

= $\frac{n!\times r+n!\times(n-r+1)}{r!(n-r+1)!}$

= $\frac{n!(r+n-r+1)}{r!(n-r+1)!}$

= $\frac{(n+1)!}{r!(n+1-r)!}$

= ${n+1\choose r}$$x^{r}$

Assuming the given solution is correct, I would like some guidance on where I have gone wrong.

Comment: If you don´t post your steps we cannot know where you have gone wrong. Btw, you should accept $\left(\color{limegreen}{\checkmark}\right)$ answers which help you to answer your questions.

Comment: Maybe you used a faulty formula for $n\choose r$. It's hard to tell, since you haven't shown us what you did.

Comment: I have now given details of my working, thanks.

Comment: Going from 3rd line to 4th, you cancelled one factor of $(r-1)!$ from each term in the numerator, but two factors of $(r-1)!$ from the denominator.

Comment: That would be it, thanks!